# Libgdx: How to draw the score on the top left?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, ios

I want to keep the score visible on the top left corner of the screen. I have the score talking care of. I just want to display it.

`Score: x`

The comment on the accepted answer on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127201/libgdx-add-scores-display-it-at-top-left-corner-of-the-screen) suggests that `BitmapFontCache` is the best way to do it, inside the render method.

- `BitmapFontCache.draw()` doesn't accept strings, so I cannot pass
  `Score:`
- `BitmapFontCache.draw(batch, x, Align.topLeft);` doesn't work either.
- Do I have to keep updating the score position?

**EDIT**

```
  game.batch.begin();
        cache.setText("Score: " + score, 500,500);
        cache.draw(game.batch);
```

.........

or even if I placed it outside `batch.begin`, if I place it directly in, I get

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 172645
                  Process: com.mygdx.game, PID: 16727
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.GlyphLayout com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFontCache.setText(java.lang.CharSequence, float, float)' on a null object reference
                      at com.mygdx.game.GameScreen.render(GameScreen.java:129)
                      at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
                      at com.mygdx.game.Gam.render(Gam.java:20)
                      at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:459)
                      at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1647)
                      at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1352)
E/AndroidGraphics: waiting for pause synchronization took too long; assuming deadlock and killing
```

Even if I remove `score` variable and put everything outside batch.begin but inside render I keep getting the same error.

```
 public void render(float delta) {
        cache.setText("Score: " + 12, 500,500);
        cache.draw(game.batch);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To set the text you have to use

   ```
   BitmapFontCache.setText(text, x, y);
   ```
2. In the render method you just do

   ```
   BitmapFontCache.draw(batch);
   ```
3. You only have to update the score position once in the render method.

Comment: and how to pass the `int x`

Comment: varx = 22;  BitmapFontCache.setText("score: "+varx, x,y);

Comment: I'm getting ` java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.GlyphLayout com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFontCache.setText(java.lang.CharSequence, float, float)' on a null object reference`

Comment: why would that happen

Comment: Try paste the code that make it a lot easier.

Comment: sure first thing tomorrow it's 3 am now. Thx for ur help

Comment: please read my edit

Comment: I think it is because you have forgot to instantialize the variable score or it has something to do with this game.batch.begin();.

Comment: please read my second edit

Comment: Can you try do it in the game class. so it instead of cache.draw(game.batch); it will be cache.draw(batch);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53851/discussion-between-klemmensen-and-lynob).

Comment: Im not notified when you post in the chat, anyhow I replied.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for `Klemmensen` I ended up doing

```
game.font.setColor(Color.WHITE);
game.font.draw(game.batch, "Score: " +score, x, y);
```